# How can I reduce the space between individual CardViews in a RecyclerView?

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview, cardview

So I was learning to implement RecyclerViews along with CardViews. I'm finding that these individual CardViews have a lot of space between them. Here's the XML code for the RecyclerView as well as the CardView.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bannerId"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/favorite_artists_text"
        android:textSize="27sp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_alternates_bold"/>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/RecyclerView"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/bannerId"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_marginTop="65dp"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**layout_listitems.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/primaryCardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    app:cardMaxElevation="1dp"
    app:cardElevation="1dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/housingRelativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="3dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rank"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/old_standard_tt_bold"
            android:text="@string/sample_rank"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="27sp" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/separator_line"
            style="@style/separator_line"
            android:layout_below="@id/rank"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/songName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/separator_line"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:text="@string/sample_song_name"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/varela_round"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/artistName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/songName"
            android:text="@string/sample_artist_name"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/varela_round"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

I checked out a few other answers here in Stack Overflow and one of them said that adding these lines:

```
app:cardMaxElevation="1dp"
app:cardElevation="1dp"
```

would fix the issue. But, it did nothing.

Answer (score 2):

because you are using `android:layout_margin="10dp"` for `cardView` which mean you will add `10dp` space all sides, the first  item has now `10dp` top & bottom, when adding the second item for `recyclerView` will add another `10dp` on top so, now the second item has `20dp` margin space.

How to fix?

you can set margins using top, start and end only.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: it's my pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

Just like Moustafa EL-Saghier's solution, by putting this line of code in your XML

```
android:layout_margin="10dp"
```

You are basically telling the program to put 10dp worth of space in between all of your cards in the RecyclerView, including the sides.

For a horizontal RecyclerView, you would want to put:

```
android:layout_marginStart ="10dp"
android:layout_marginEnd = "10dp"
```

This will put space in between the cards on the left and right hand sides.

For a vertical Recyclerview, you would want to put:

```
android:layout_marginTop ="10dp"
android:layout_marginBottom = "10dp"
```

This will put space in between the cards on the top and bottom sides.

Again, this is just like Moustafa EL-Saghier's answer, just in a way that addresses your Cardview needs in simple code bits. Hope this helps!